# python face detect problem can someone help me

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I followed a totorial by sentdex and downloaded his code but i still get errors and i have no idea how to fix this. The code is written in python btw.
My code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# multiple cascades: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades

#https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
#https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while 1:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray)

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)

    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

### Error

```py
[ WARN:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (1113) SourceReaderCB::OnReadSample videoio(MSMF): OnReadSample() is called with error status: -2147023169
[ WARN:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (1125) SourceReaderCB::OnReadSample videoio(MSMF): async ReadSample() call is failed with error status: -2147023169
[ WARN:1] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (1159) CvCapture_MSMF::grabFrame videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -2147023169
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FaceDetect.py", line 15, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

[ WARN:1] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (674) SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

I got help from someone (sorry I don't remember your username) who told me to do this

```py
path = cv2.data.haarcascades
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(path + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(path + 'haarcascade_eye.xml')
```

but i still get errors like this

```py
[ WARN:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (1113) SourceReaderCB::OnReadSample videoio(MSMF): OnReadSample() is called with error status: -2147023170
[ WARN:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (1125) SourceReaderCB::OnReadSample videoio(MSMF): async ReadSample() call is failed with error status: -2147023170
[ WARN:1] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (1159) CvCapture_MSMF::grabFrame videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -2147023170
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FaceDetect.py", line 18, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

[ WARN:1] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (674) SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

Comment: the !_src.empty() likely means the img variable is empty or invalid.

Answer (score 1):

try to change API settings:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW) #Change API settings
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like your code actually works, but the only thing I can think of is to try to change the cv2 inside the classifiers pointing to the xml's inside the cv2 library. Before the CascadeClassifiers it should be something like this :

```
...
import cv2

path = cv2.data.haarcascades
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(path + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(path + 'haarcascade_eye.xml')
...
```

Comment: can you see  if there is an error or if you have any other similar ideas that could work. Thanks